# iPhone lost and erased for no reason

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, find-my-iphone, activation-lock

I've had my iPhone for 2 years, and this has never happened before. I turned airplane mode off and my phone screen turned white with the apple logo and had a loading bar underneath it. Once it reloaded, it informed me that everything was erased off of my phone.

Now it won't let me use the Apple ID log in. It states that the owner used 'find my iPhone' to erase everything.

I have never used 'Find my iPhone'. What is happening here?

Answer (score 3):

If you bought the phone from some other person, and not from an official store, the seller might have stolen the iPhone and sold it to you and now the owner is looking for it (I doubt it since you had it for 2 years)

If you bought your phone from the official store, your iCloud ID might have been hacked. The solution to activating it would be to go to an Apple store, prove to them that you are the rightful owner and they will reset it for you. After that, if you have a backup, restore the phone from the backup. Also, change your iCloud ID password **Immediately**. If you cannot log in, it might have been hijacked. In that case, click forgot password and reset from email.

Comment: Yeah see the problem is that I am in Turkey, there isn't a whole lot of apple stores here and if there is they probably don't speak english

Comment: You can get Apple to ring you for that kind of issue - if you have a US/UK/English phone number they can call, even if it's a mobile abroad or someone else's phone, then you get someone English calling you. [I just had to do similar from Spain last week - they had me fixed in 5 mins] Start at https://www.apple.com/support/contact/